# Error Saving ViewState in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I am working in .NET Entity Framework 4.0
I am using viewstate to save an entity. And I have serialize that entity as well. But when I try to save data to viewstate, getting this error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Error serializing value 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Pc.PrecisionCare2.ModelTypes.Medication]' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Pc.PrecisionCare2.ModelTypes.Medication, PrecisionCare2ModelTypes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].'
```

Comment: Is it possible to see more code?

Comment: May I also ask why you are using Viewstate and not Session? It depends on your requirment but the reason I ask is because im sure you already know this but the life scope of ViewState is wihin the current page, which means when you move to another page, then the ViewState will be destroyed automaticaly. Session object, however, is stored in memory on the web server and thus is available to any page until the Session is expired or the application session is terminated, or destroyed manually in your code.

Comment: I'm using this with the current page. And the problem was, my entity was containing another entity as well. And I was not serializing the contained entity. That's why this error occur. I serialize the contained entity and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help anyone. I wanted to serialize a entity in the Viewstate myself and couldn't find a good solution (XMLSerialization, Byte Serializing, DataContract). What I found out is that I could "extend" the code generated classes (they are partial) and make it Serializable.

For example this is a .net code generated entity:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace OAuthServerBroker.EF
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ResourceOwner
    {
        public ResourceOwner()
        {
            this.Grant = new HashSet<Grant>();
        }

        public System.Guid ResourceOwner_ID { get; set; }
        public string ResourceOwner_Username { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Grant> Grant { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I create a new class file with the same class name and namespace I can make the Entity Serializable :).

```
using System;

namespace OAuthServerBroker.EF
{
    [Serializable]
    public partial class ResourceOwner
    {
        public EntityState State { get; set; } //can even put into new properties
    }
}
```

Hope this might help anyone since it's an old post :(.